# How to receive DB2 stored procedure result in LotusScript

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have the following DB2 stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SCHEME.getData(IN inputParam VARCHAR(100), OUT outputParam VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    -- do sth
    SET outputParam = 'something2';
END
```

I want to run this procedure with on param and receive the result in the LotusScript agent:

```
Set con = New ODBCConnection
Set qry = New ODBCQuery
Set result = New ODBCResultSet

Call con.ConnectTo("MyOdbcDriverName", "user", "pass")

Set result.Query = qry
Set qry.Connection = con


sql = |Call SCHEME.getData('arg1')|//it runs ok - no odbc errors

qry.Sql = sql
result.Execute

If result.Isresultsetavailable() Then    //false here so no idea how to process the result
    REM do sth with result
    value = result.GetValue(1)      
Else
```

What should I add to the SQL statement and how should I process the result in order to receive the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method `ODBCResultSet.ExecProcedure`, so something like this might work:

```
Dim inputParm as String
Dim outputParm as String

Set inputParm = 'arg1'
result.ExecProcedure('SCHEME.GETDATA',inputParm,outputParm)

Print outputParm
```

Note that you probably want to use the uppercase procedure name.

[Link to the manual page.](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/cdfe94a784b7c6518525731b004b5d17?OpenDocument)

Comment: This solution ends with the "missing parameter in query" error

Comment: Please see the edit: there is a special method in `ODBCResultSet` for calling procedures.

Comment: Your solution works for me too now. It's a little bit better than the one I found earlier because it does not require adding hardcoded parameter names.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following solution work for me. It uses LCConnection class instead of ODBCConnection

```
Dim sess As New LCSession
Dim conn As New LCConnection ("db2")

'set the connection parameters...
conn.Database = "ODBCSourceName"
conn.UserId = "user"
conn.Password = "pass"

'connect to the database...
conn.Connect    

'set the stored procedure owner and stored procedure name...            
conn.Procedure = "SCHEME.getData"

'set Fieldnames property with any output parameters declared in 
'the stored procedure...
conn.Fieldnames = "outputParam" 'stored procedure output param name



'declare any fields and fieldlists for input/output data...

Dim inputParams As New LCFieldList
Dim outputParams As New LCFieldlist
Dim inputValue As LCField
Dim outputValue As LCField

Dim out As Double

'set the input parameters of the stored procedure...                
Set inputValue = inputParams.Append ("inputParam", LCTYPE_TEXT) 'stored procedure input param name                  
inputValue.Value = "my input value"                 


'with the input parameters set, call the stored procedure...
'the declared output_parms fieldlist will hold the output parameters 
'of the stored procedure...

out = conn.Call (inputParams, 1, outputParams)

'fetch parameter(s) into the output_parms fieldlist...
out = conn.Fetch (outputParams) 

'retrieve the parameter(s) from the output_parms fieldlist...
Set outputValue = outputParams.GetField (1)         

'do somethin with the result
Print outputValue.Value(0)
```

More info:

- http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lei/70/lccon7.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/780c155f1003f49785256edf005b26c9?OpenDocument
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/DB2-procedures/